# Hide UIImageView in TableViewCell for Constraint Purposes

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have my tableViewCell set up for

```
UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

However, some cells will not have a UIImage. I would like the cell to adjust size if it doesnt contain an image. How can I set the height of the cell in a proper manner to where i can accomplish this.

[image]

I would like to make the cell adjust to the height of the autoDimension of the textView(above the imageView in storyboard) if the image is missing. Whats the best way to go about this?

[image]

**UPDATE*:**

So i did exactly what you said but i did it with a identifier rather than an IBAction.

```
  if let c = messageImage.constraint(withIdentifier: "imageViewHeightConstraint") {
                    // do stuff with c

                    if(messageArray[indexPath.row].uploadedPhotoUrl == ""){
                        c.constant = 1
                    }else {
                        c.constant = 162
                    }

                    // c.constant =  (messageArray[indexPath.row].uploadedPhotoUrl == "") ? 1 : 162
                }

let filter = AspectScaledToFillSizeFilter(size: messageImage.frame.size)
messageImage.af_setImage(withURL: messageImageDownloadUrl! as URL, filter: filter)

cell?.layoutIfNeeded()
return cell!
```

UI:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hook the height constraint of the `UIImageview` as IBOutlet and inside `cellForRow`

```
cell.imageVHeightCon.constant = ( image == nil ) ? 0 : 200
cell.layoutIfNeeded()
return cell
```

Comment: what is hide..?

Comment: it's according to your logic whether the image exists or not

Answer (score 0):

The good way is using horizontal stackview

and when you don't need imageview set imageview.isHidden = true